# how to start overriding file after it reaches certain size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Is there a way to start overriding a file when it reaches, for example, 50 MB size?

Currently I started with:

```
with open("mylogfile.log", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(something)
```

I want to keep adding text at the end of my file as long as it is under 50 MB size. Then, I want to start overriding, I mean saving the new lines of text but delete the text from the beginning of the file.

How do I do that?

Comment: Use the `RotatingFileHandler` of the `logging` package: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/02/11/python-how-to-create-rotating-logs/ Please do *not* implement your own logging framework.

Comment: Is this some kind of primitive logging you try to implement?

Comment: Of course, the logging package is the obvious choice for real projects. This example is just a part of some kind of practice. Anyway, thanks for being vigilant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the path module to check the size

to have a bigger idea [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-size-method)

**os.path.getsize() method in Python is used to check the size of specified path. It returns the size of specified path in bytes. The method raise OSError if the file does not exist or is somehow inaccessible.**

```py
import os
def write(filename,text):
    if os.path.size(filename) <= 50*100_000: # is bigger or equal to 50 Million
        return False
    with open(filename) as file:
        file.write(text)
    return True
```